# Are muskmellons self-fertile?

Tags: pollination

I am experimenting with muskmellons this year.

Starting from seeds I kept from a melon I bought last year I was having 3 nice seedlings by the end of April. Putting them outside in May (and hoping that the weather will be warm) I had to witness 2 of them dying. But one of them is still there and now it starts flowering.

I'm sure that there are no other mellon plants nearby - hence my question: Are muskmellons self-fertile? Will I get fruits from my lonely plant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curcumis melo -- the entire group of melons -- are monoecious, meaning individual flowers are either male or female, but a single plant produces both male and female flowers.

[See "Plants For A Future"](http://www.pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Cucumis%20melo%20cantalupensis)

Answer (score 3):

Muskmelon flowers are self-fertile, but require insects to transfer pollen. There must be sufficient bee activity during the one day the female flower is open to insure that more than 400 seeds are formed. Fruit with less than 400 seeds are usually so small they are classified as culls